# How to specify overlapping rules in git-svn

Tags: git, git-svn

I need to fetch revisions from SVN into GIT.
I have two types of branches under SVN:

1. Standard branches located in /branches folder under SVN
2. Some specific branches located under /branches/devs/ folders

To fetch both types of branches i have specified the following configuration in svn-remote section:

```
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://somecompany.com/product

    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/trunk
    fetch = tools:refs/remotes/root/tools

    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/*
    branches = branches/devs/*/*:refs/remotes/devs/*/*

    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/tags/*
```

Unfortunately, for the second type of branches fetch is executed twice.
Once treating devs as an ordinary branch and second time in a right way: working with individual branches of developers.

So far, I manually comment either first or second "branches" and specify what revisions to fetch based on what branches were affected by commits.

Could anybody suggest a way to automate (fix) the above somehow?

Thanks,

Serhiy Y

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put the more specific one first because some of the code (including `git-svn branch`) searches them in order.  The problem you're hitting is that internally `fetch_all` just combines them all.  There's no way to write this at the moment that would avoid the double fetch.